# Python assertEquals generator

Tags: python

I'm unit testing a generator object that contains objects. I wanna check the objects value property to see if it contains the number, as expected.

The generator object contains 5 object instances from class Test. So I wanna do something like this:

pseudo code:
All Test instance object's value property (test.value), in generator object (to list) is equal to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Is this possible to achieve using a one line for loop or something inside the assertEquals method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's only 5 elements, just use a list comprehension.

```
assertEqual([test.value for test in test_instance_objects], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you! The first example is what I meant, and it works great. Since you are mentioning "only 5", I'm guessing this is an ineffective approach?

Comment: Once you're using large datasets (say, 10000 elements in your generator), you don't necessarily want to keep all of those elements in memory at the same time. So once you get that large, I'd recommend doing a for-loop over the generator instead of the list comprehension. 5 elements is nowhere near the size that would make me concerned though.

Comment: When trying the latter example I'm getting: "AssertionError: First sequence has no length. Non-sequence?"

Comment: You're correct. I was using `xrange()` as my test. Blah. Then I think I'm just reverting to my original statements that still exist on this answer.